# SourceTree is freezing when trying to preview changes to a config.codekit3 file

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, codekit

Why is SourceTree freezing when it's trying to preview changes to a .codekit3 file?

When I select (or SourceTree automatically selects) the config.codekit3, it's freezing completely and the only thing I can do is to force-quit SourceTree. Too many changes in one go to a (relatively) large file?

And is it normal for a config.codekit3 to take up almost 400kb? I've set up a small web project and installed 4 node modules via the CodeKit3 UI. The CodeKit project builds with no issues or warnings and doesn't take longer than expected to do so.

Also, the config file looks completely fine after pushing to remote. Restarting SourceTree or machine didn't help. It's still freezing when I select the respective commit from the History panel.

[image: SourceTree Freeze]